# How Do I Properly Use iCarouselOptions with iOS iCarousel?

Tags: ios, swift, icarousel

I'm creating an iOS app with Swift and am using iCarousel from GitHub (installed via cocoapods) and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't seem to get iCarouselOptions I set to have any effect...

What I want to do is simply change the spacing of the UIViews in my carousel (They are too close together and overlapping, which I don't want).

Here is my code:

```
    import UIKit
    import iCarousel

    class MiniGamesViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDelegate, iCarouselDataSource {

        //Objects
        @IBOutlet weak var leaveMinigamesButton: UIButton!

        //Variables
        var carouselHeight : CGFloat!
        var selectionBallSize : CGFloat!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            leaveMinigamesButton.layer.zPosition = 3
            carouselHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - 200
            selectionBallSize = self.view.frame.size.width * 0.65

            let carousel = iCarousel(frame: CGRect(
                x: 0,
                y: 100,
                width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                height: carouselHeight))

            carousel.perspective = -0.005
            carousel.centerItemWhenSelected = true
            carousel.decelerationRate = 0.9
            carousel.viewpointOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0) //-selectionBallSize * 1.2

            carousel.dataSource = self
            carousel.type = .rotary
            view.addSubview(carousel)
        }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }

        //This is how many items there will be in my rotary iCarousel
        func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
            return 6
        }

        //This defines each item or 'cell' in the iCarousel
        func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
            let imageView: UIImageView
            if view != nil {
                imageView = view as! UIImageView
            } else {
                imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: selectionBallSize, height: selectionBallSize))
            }
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "orbCyan")
            return imageView
        }

        func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            switch (option) {
            case .spacing: return value * 2
            case .radius: return 200
            case .fadeMinAlpha: return 0.5
            default: return value
            }
        }
}
```

Specifically the very bottom of my code is where the customization
is supposed to take effect, but it doesn't seem to be making any changes when I run the app. At the moment, I'm only concerned with trying to space the UIViews in the carousel to be further apart.

Am I putting the iCarouselOptions function in the right place? Is it even being 'called' at all?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you know it, as soon as I posted this question I found the issue haha (after a day of trying everything). Turns out I was missing the simple line:

```
carousel.delegate = self
```

underneath:

```
carousel.dataSource = self
```

That totally did the trick and it works now lol. I need a fresh set of eyes :P